# Automated UML2 class diagram

Tags: java, macos, uml

Is there any application that can look to my Java code and create UML2 class diagrams? I could not find anything. I have a Mac and I am using Netbeans.

Comment: Open google.com, and type "java code to uml", you are going to find *A TON* of free/commercial tools which does this thing.

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans does not have anymore UML plugins. You therefore need to select another framework such as Eclipse with UML eclipse based UML tools or to select a standalone tool such as Visual paradigm, MetaUML, EA etc....

Answer (score 0):

What version of Netbeans are you running? If you have an old version [this](http://blogs.oracle.com/JavaFundamentals/entry/generating_uml_from_the_netbeans) tutorial might be useful. If you have a more recent one, [this](http://forums.netbeans.org/topic28035.html) Netbeans forum post might be useful.

On the other hand, you might consider installing [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) and install the [eUML2](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/euml2-free-edition) plugin:

> eUML2 for Java is a powerful UML modeler designed for Java developper
>   in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Paradigm has a [community edition](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/product/vpuml/editions/community.jsp) which allows for [reverse and forward engineering](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/product/vpuml/provides/roundtripcodeengine.jsp). Although if you use eclipse i would agree with npinti and opt for the eUML2 plugin.